# Making URL a beautiful thing to look at using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, query-string, permalinks

Most of my URL is fine thanks to Wordpress %postname% permalinks.

I would still like to change few query strings like **?edit=** when editing post and **?updated=true** if you submit your edit.

Could anyone give me a fast example with few comments which I could use to work my way up?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

// I have no idea what comes here

</IfModule>
```

1) **www.mywebsite.com/post-template/?edit=3242 <-- number is post ID**

How to show only post ID after /     OR replace ?edit= with word "potatoe" for example?

2) **www.mywebsite.com/post-template/?updated=true <-- I have no idea how to change that, no ID's or anything**

How to replace ?updated=true with word "carrot"  for example?

I usually go grazy and start testing but I read that errors in .htaccess can cause some serious things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^edit/(.*)$ theprocess.php?edit=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^edit/(.*)/submitit$ theprocess.php?edit=$1&updated=true [L]
</IfModule>
```

The above is a sample for you to start (assuming the php file you're working with is called theprocess.php).

You will want to look into regular expressions because you'll use a lot of them with RewriteRules. The important thing is `$1` will be replaced with the actual value in `()` which in this case is `.*` meaning "match anything" at that point. So in the examples, if one types `http://example.com/edit/123` then whats being processed is `theprocess.php?edit=123`

Comment: Could you be so kind and edit your answer little bit so that I could understand a little better? I'll add few extra lines to my question.

Comment: For a rewriterule to work, you need two URLs. The friendly one (a.k.a. the beautiful thing) and the not-so-friendly one (a.k.a. the one with a file extension and question mark). So one of your unfriendly url's is `www.mywebsite.com/post-template/?edit=3242`. You need a friendly version that includes that number in it. maybe like `www.mywebsite.com/editpost/number/3242`? Decide on the non-friendly urls and the friendly urls you want to associate with each non-friendly url.